# Always image cannot be sent normally What is wrong in my code?

Tags: python, django

Always image cannot be sent normally. I wrote in views.py

```
def photo(request):
    d = {
        'photos': Post.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', d)

def upload_save(request):
    form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        data = form.save(commit=False)
        data.user = request.user
        data.save()
        return render(request, 'registration/photo.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/profile.html')
```

in profile.html

```
<main>
        <div>
              <img class="absolute-fill">

          <div class="container" id="photoform">

          <form action="/accounts/upload_save/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
            {% csrf_token %}

          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label>
                    <input id="file1" type="file" name="image1" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>

          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label>
                    <input id="file2" type="file" name="image2" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>
          　　
          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label>
                    <input id="file3" type="file" name="image3" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id" class="form-control">
            </div>
              <input id="send" type="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control">

          </form>
        </div>

        </div>

        </div>
    </main>
```

in forms.py

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields = ('image',)
```

n my system,I can send 3 images at most each one time, so there are 3 blocks.Now always program goes into else statement in upload_save method, I really cannot understand why always form.is_valid() is valid.When I send only 1 image, same thing happens.So the number of image does not cause the error. When I print out print(form.errors) ,it is `<ul class="errorlist"><li>image<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required</li></ul></li></ul>`  How should I fix ?What is wrong in my code?

Comment: you have defined 'image' as field name and your form doesn't contain an input field with name as 'image' . You can change to 'image1 = forms.ImageField()' and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not passing context in render function. If that doesn't work use this approach to save the images.

```
def function(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
         if form.is_valid():

             image = form.cleaned_data.get('image')
             image2  = form.cleaned_data.get("image2")
             user = request.user 

             Post.objects.create(
                User = request.user, 
                image= image,
                image2= image2,
               )
             return redirect('SOMEWHERE')
    else:
        form = UserImageForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html',{'form': form})
```